# Output selenium test result as html after running perl script

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently looking for a way to output the test result nicely after running selenium perl script.

The htmlSuite command from running selenium server outputs a nice html format result page, but I don't know how to do that in perl script.

Problem is, I have it setup so that Selenium is being run 24/7 on a virtual machine workstation(Windows 7), where anyone one can run tests on. Therefore I can't use htmlSuite to run the test because the server will close after the test is finished.

Is there a command argument or perl script method to make selenium server output results on html or other nice format other than printing it on the command line?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your script is output TAP (that's what Test::More would put out), then you can use the Test::Harness family of modules to parse that TAP and use it to generate an HTML report.

Answer (score 0):

How nice is nice? Under Hudson/Jenkins this gives graphs and a tabular report of tests run:

```
prove --timer --formatter=TAP::Formatter::JUnit large_test.t >junit.xml
```